# sliksvn displays popup, "There is no disk in the drive"

Tags: windows, svn

**Problem**:

I use the SlikSVN command line client and Windows 8.1 machine. When I type `svn update` in any folder, a message box appears that says, "There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive F:"  I cannot stop or explain why sliksvn pops up this message.

**Screenshot**:

[image: Screenshot of popup message]

**Question**: Do you know what might cause this?

**More details**:

- After pressing Continue a couple times, it finally does the update.
- It happens for svn update and checkout, but not for svn status and info.
- I have tried clearing my SVN credentials.
- I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling SlikSVN.
- I do a custom install and only install the client and tools.
- I have not noticed that it happens for any other program.
- My computer is just a few weeks old.
- My F: drive corresponds to an SD port on my computer. I have never used that SD port before.
- My SlikSVN version is version 1.8.5-SlikSvn-1.8.5-X64 (SlikSvn/1.8.5) X64 compiled Nov 30 2013, 17:17:43 on x86_64-microsoft-windows6.2.9200
- I reported this using the contact form on the SlikSVN website, but have not received a response yet.

Comment: Does it happen if you run `svn update --ignore-externals`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yes, it happens if I run with the --ignore-externals switch. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the [SlikSVN site](http://www.sliksvn.com/pub/) again. On January 18, they uploaded a new version, 1.8.5-1. I did the following:

- Uninstalled version 1.8.5
- Deleted my AppData\Roaming\Subversion folder
- Installed version 1.8.5-1

I no longer get the annoying popup message about drive F:.

As best I can tell, version 1.8.5-1 fixed the problem.

Comment: Certainly, their home page says: "Note: Version 1.8.5-1 resolves a problem where drive F: is incorrectly accessed, and contains a minor security fix in OpenSSL.". Thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a removable USB? 
Is it labelled C:\? 
Microsoft doesn't like it

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/error-please-insert-a-disk-into-drive/120f2e69-7b47-4eba-aff0-b9f0c6486c27

Comment: There are *no* USB drives plugged into my computer. Thanks for the suggestion.